# Esper EventBean and EPStatement Association

Tags: java, esper

Is there anyway to relate the output of an Esper EventBean object back to the original EPStatement that produced the result using Java?

I have a number of EPStatements defined that use the @Name annotation but I noticed that this value is not present in the resulting EventBean. I need this value so I can uniquely identify the EventBeans that are produced.

Alternatively, is there is some way to attach an additional field that will be present in a resulting EventBean object after Esper outputs a result? This would also work for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a StatementAwareUpdateListener interface that delivers the statement object together with EventBean output.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Implementing this interface I am able to retrieve the annotations from the EPStatement that produced a result.